# Xcode XCTest profile with C++

Tags: c++, xcode, xctest, profile

I am trying to profile in XCode for a Cpp program that is currently using XCTest for testing some of the functions. Is there a way that I can see the detailed time for the unit functions instead of only the high level one? 
I attached the image below for your reference. Thanks for the attention.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0GZo.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: Enter your code here, do not link to images.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've already solved that problem! In short, we need to link those unit tests to an executable...